# Vue.js add the same class repeatedly to create a "just updated" effect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Goal:**

I have a list of items and when something changes on one of those items, I want to draw the user's attention to it by making it have a yellow background that fades out to transparent.

**How I'm attempting to do this:**

My Vue instance has a list of `items`.

Each item has a property, `isChanged`, which is a boolean value indicating whether that item has been changed by some action in the interface.

I've binded a class to the items so that when their `isChanged` property is true, the class `highlight` is added.

```
<ul v-for='item in items' :key='item.id'>
    <li :class="{ 'highlight' : item.isChanged>{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

The highlight class simply changes the background to yellow then fades it to transparent:

```
.highlight {
    animation: yellowfadingbox 4s;
}

@keyframes yellowfadingbox {
    from {
        background: @yellow;
    }
    to {
        background: transparent;
    }
}
```

So, as an example, I have a method `updateItem` that makes an ajax call and when it's done, sets that items `isChanged` property to true.

```
updateItem: function (itemKey) {
            axios.get('/item/update', {
                params: {
                    id: id,
                }
            }).then(response => {
                this.item[itemKey].isChanged = true;
            });
        }
```

This works in that it adds the appropriate `highlight` class to the item, giving me the effect I want. However, moving forward, that `highlight` class always exists and so I can not recreate the effect.

How can I fix this approach/is there a smarter approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you might do it.

I'm using a transition rather than an animation. Adding the `highlight` class sets the background to yellow. I then remove it again to get the transition back to transparent.

I'm using `requestAnimationFrame` to delay so that the transition has chance to take effect. There are two problems that the delay addresses. Firstly, we need to give Vue chance to render. Secondly, we need to give the browser chance to apply the yellow background (style recalc), otherwise the transition won't happen. There are various ways to achieve these two things. `$nextTick` could be used to overcome the first problem but we'd still need some way to kick the browser into applying the style. That gets fiddly as you'd need to grab a reference to the relevant element and then use `getComputedStyle` to force the style recalc on the `background-color`. `requestAnimationFrame` seemed a relatively painless solution by comparison.

In this example just click on the items to see the effect.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
        name: 'Red',
        id: 1,
        isChanged: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Green',
        id: 2,
        isChanged: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Blue',
        id: 3,
        isChanged: false
      },
      {
        name: 'Yellow',
        id: 4,
        isChanged: false
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    onClick (item) {
      item.isChanged = true;
      
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        item.isChanged = false;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.list-item {
  transition: background-color 4s;
}

.list-item.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item.id"
      :class="{ 'highlight' : item.isChanged}"
      class="list-item"
      @click="onClick(item)"
    >
      {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```